# best way to created set of named objects in Python

Tags: python

I find myself frequently creating sets of named objects where each object has a unique name.  I implement these as `dict`s whose keys are derived from `myObject.name`.  But this feels a bit clunky to keep the name in two places.

My typical approach looks like this:

```
class NamedObject(object):
    ITEMS = {}

    def __init__(self, name, ...other arguments...):
        self.name = name
        ...more initialization...

    @classmethod
    def create_named_object(cls, name, ...other arguments...):
        obj = cls(name, ...other arguments...)
        cls.ITEMS[name] = obj

    @classmethod
    def find_object_by_name(cls, name):
        return cls.ITEMS.get(name, None)

    @classmethod
    def filter_objects(cls, predicate):
        return [e for e in cls.ITEMS.values() if predicate(e)]
```

I know I could create a generalized class to handle this, but is there a more naturally Pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no more generalised support in the standard library, no, nor is there any more 'Pythonic' way to achieve this than using a dictionary.

What you are doing is providing an [*lookup table index*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table), and indices generally require some duplication of data. You are trading memory for access speed. But indices are *use-case specific* and either trivially implemented with a mapping, or too specific to the application to be generalisable to the level that adding that to the language library makes sense.

At least in Python, the string value for the name is not actually duplicated; you just add more references to it; once from the instance and another time from the `ITEMS` dictionary.

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't so worried about using extra storage as much as the conceptual overhead of keeping two references to the same string.  What I'd find useful is a 'key' argument to the `set` (or `frozenset`) class that lets you use an accessor on an object rather than the object itself for determining keys for the `set` (or `frozenset`).

Comment: You mean like [`__hash__` and `__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable)? You can trivially create a wrapper object that implements hashing and equality testing based on an attribute you name (or a key function), or have the class implement these directly.  A wrapper adds a bit of overhead though (I'd make sure to use `__slots__` and cache the key function outcome and hash).